# From PostgreSQL to Postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I've got a trouble here. I have two tables in postgres with columns 'lat' and 'lon'. How to convert them into postgis geom(Point) and calculate distance between those points? I'm newbie, so help me please :)

Comment: A good starting piont would be the [geometry constructing functions](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/reference.html#Geometry_Constructors), especially `makepoint`

Comment: Thank's a lot. But how to calculate min_distance btw 2 points, that store in a different tables?

Comment: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html gives you complete examples...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, [see this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24487/1872) (or even [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/58630/1872)).

```
-- Add a spatial column with EPSG:4326 (WGS84)
ALTER TABLE some_table ADD COLUMN geom geometry(Point, 4326);

-- Use coordinates to create point geometries
UPDATE some_table SET
  geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon, lat), 4326);
```

Then to calculate the distances of each point to another point, use something like this:

```
SELECT t1.gid, t2.gid, ST_Distance(t1.geom, t2.geom)
FROM some_table t1, some_table t2
WHERE t1.gid > t2.gid;
```

Be aware the distance will be Cartesian, based on degrees, so is actually non-sense. Consider either using a `geography` type (instead of `geometry`) to get a distance result in metres, or use [`ST_Distance_Sphere`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance_Sphere.html) or  [`ST_Distance_Spheroid`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html) with `geometry`.